# AWS Bucket Policy Invalid Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having some trouble with AWS Bucket policies, I followed the instruction and it doesn't let me set the policy, so I can't get my domain to work with the buckets.

Here is a picture. The tutorial told me to replace example.com with my bucket name.

[image]

I've been trying to set up my buckets with my domain for over a month now and I just can't seem to get it going. I already purchased my domain, and it's the exact domain name I want, so I don't want to be forced to go to Bluehost with a new domain.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / input / error message as text in addition to screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple:

- Your bucket is called `www.justdiditonline.com`
- Your bucket policy is attempting to create a rule for a bucket named `justdiditonline.com`
- **The bucket names do not match**

Solution: Use a policy with the correct bucket name:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.justdiditonline.com/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I notice you have another bucket called `justdiditonline.com`. Your existing policy would work on that bucket.

The [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) instructions detail what to do, and they work fine with an external DNS service using a `CNAME` to point to the static website URL. The main steps are:

- Create a bucket with the domain name `www.justdiditonline.com`
- Add a bucket policy to **make content public**, or make sure the individual objects you want to serve are publicly readable
- Activate **Static Website Hosting** on the bucket, which will return a URL like: `www.justdiditonline.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
- Create a **DNS entry** for `www.justdiditonline.com` with a `CNAME` pointing to the Static Website Hosting URL

Comment: Thank you for that, that solved one of my problems! But my domain is still not associating with the amazon web endpoints, I created both record sets for each bucket, ugh, I just don't know what to do, I've followed the instruction word for word.

Comment: Added instructions for static website hosting.