# Amazon Web Services Route 53 / S3 unable to point to my registered domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is another problem I am having, here is the info.

My endpoint for the first bucket works, but not the 2nd bucket, and using my domain name in the browser just doesn't work at all.

Once again I have taken screenshots, this is driving me insane, I have no idea how to correct it, it just doesn't find my root or something.

[Record Sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afT9z.png)

[Buckets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCDCd.png)

I can't post more than 2 links

If anyone can help me, even PM me, I'll give my login details to take a look, because I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Just for reference, this question is a follow-up to: [AWS Bucket Policy Invalid Resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446708/aws-bucket-policy-invalid-resource/40447004)

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of AWS-related but non-programming questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Comment: Note that your second endpoint probably works perfectly fine when accessed directly -- it's "successfully" redirecting you to a your main site, which is what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the directions on [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

For the first bucket, the steps are:

- Create an **Amazon S3 bucket** with the same name as your domain (`justdiditonlne.com`)
- Add a **bucket policy** to make the content public, or modify desired objects to make them publicly accessible
- Turn on **Static Website Hosting**, and you will receive a URL like: `justdiditonline.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
- Create a **Route 53** entry for `justdiditonline.com`, type `A`, set `Alias=Yes` and enter the static website hosting URL

For the second bucket:

- Create an **Amazon S3 Bucket** with the desired domain name (`www.justdiditonline.com`)
- Turn on **Static Website Hosting**, but this time select **Redirect all requests to another host name**. Enter `www.justdiditonline.com`.

Comment: Take a look at the WHOIS data for the domain and the screenshot from Route 53. Note the nameserver discrepancy.

Comment: Unfortunately John Rotenstein, the Static Website endpoint is not a valid entry into the Alias part, and I've done all those steps more than 3 times now, I'm so stumped, Also the www.justdiditonline.com -> justdiditonline.com redirection doesn't even work www.justdiditonline.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com .. but the normal endpoint justdiditonline.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com works.... I'm going insane

Comment: Good catch, sqlbot! The WHOIS entry shows `ns-287.awsdns-35.com`, whereas the screenshot from Route 53 shows `ns-1995.awsdns-57.com`. Strange, because the registrar is shown as Amazon. When I try to `nslookup justdiditonline.com ns-1995.awsdns-57.co.uk` it returns REFUSED. Also, `nslookup justdiditonline.com` doesn't return anything. So, it looks like the `NS` record is incorrectly configured. @justdidit - Can you try creating the domain in Route 53, or somehow fix that `NS` record?

Comment: Still doesn't work, can someone email me at spekyr@gmail.com so ican give my username and pw, i really need this to be fixed, I'll be in your debt if you ever need a favour

Comment: Ok, I'm offering $20 dollars via Paypal for anyone that can dive into my account and solve the problem, please email me at spekyr@gmail.com

Comment: Side note: There are [AWS Support plans](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/pricing/) available to assist with problems and to answer questions about AWS services.